# How to determine if a node has a positive y axis?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to determine if a node on this diagram has a positive y axis:

[image: points]

Things I know:

- The blue node in the centre will always be at 0,0.
- second blue node will always have a positive x axis.
- second blue node will always have a y axis of 0.
- distance between the blue nodes.
- distance from any blue node to any red node.

Is there a way to look at any of the red nodes and figure out if they have a positive y value?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, you can't tell whether a given red node is above or below the horizontal axis.

Let the second blue node be at $(a,0)$. Suppose we have a red node that is distance $r_1$ from the first blue node and distance $r_2$ from the second blue node. Then the red node must lie on the circle of radius $r_1$ centered at $(0,0)$, as well as on the circle of radius $r_2$ centered at $(a,0)$. Unless the red node lies exactly on the $y$-axis, these two circles will intersect in two points: one above and one below the $y$-axis. The red node must be one of those points, but without more information we can't tell which of the two it is.

Phrased another way: a given red node has some distance $r_1$ and $r_2$ from the two blue nodes, but the reflection of the red node across the horizontal axis also has the same distances to the two blue nodes.

Comment: ok that does make sense, similar to trilateration techniques, I will need a third reference point to narrow down the possible positions from 2 to 1.

Thanks!